# What are best practices for file structure when organizing scripts?

Tags: organization, code-organization

Over the last few years, I've started dabbling in scripting using Python, R and Matlab.  My background is not in computer science, rather I'm an ecologist by training.  I've written and gathered dozens of scripts from each programming environment since I began dabbling as a computer ecologist.  To further complicate matters, I have copies of scripts from a work server that I run on personal computers.  Things have really become out of control and I hope to restructure my organizational scheme.  To date, I've loosely organized scripts by project within folders--which has led to dozens of scripts within dozens of hidden folders.  I also have folders within folders of previous versions of scripts.  Finally, my question for the experienced programmers out there:  What are some best practices for organizing years worth of old scripts and starting fresh?  For example, should I focus on a creating a central repository or is a project-based approach more appropriate?  How should I incorporate handling different, older versions of scripts?  Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep mine by language, for example

```
/opt/python
/opt/r
/opt/matlab
```

---

> I also have folders within folders of previous versions of scripts.

You my friend should discover the greatness of [**git**](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29)